# Progressive download and Caching

Tags: ios, ipad, video-streaming

I want to play the video from remote server as well as cache it locally on ipad so that next time if it is present I can play it offline also.

Does anybody had done this before? I guess progressive download is one of the option but need to understand where it get saved and can i back up these over the icloud?

Comment: Did you have any luck or progress implementing this functionality?

Comment: Not exactly, we switched to android and streams also changed to HLS on server. On Android side we downloaded ts packets in background and saved locally as stream gets played.

Answer (score 0):

In this first example I play the progressive download streaming from a simple java server 
https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/StreamX

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rdb0eKhmH4Q

then there's this one taking  a stream, in case rtsp and use alassetwriter

https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/FFPlayer-beta1/blob/master/FFAVFrames-test/ViewController.m

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mi, but can you let me know where did it get saved and how http streaming works?